# How to print a maze saved as a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, maze

I have a function that reads a maze from a .txt file and converts it into a dictionary. Dictionary's keys are the cells of the maze, and the values are the cardinal points. The 'True' value means that a wall is present in north and so on. 
This is what my function does:

```
def importa(maze):
    lab=open(maze, 'r')

    l=list(lab.readlines())
    if len(l)==0:
        return None
    righe=len(l)
    colonne=(len(l[0])-1)



    maze=dict()
    for r in range(1,righe-1,2):

        for c in range(1,colonne-1,2):

            nord=l[r-1][c]=='*'

            sud=(l[r+1][c]=='*')
            est=(l[r][c+1]=='*')
            ovest=(l[r][c-1]=='*')
            maze[(r//2,c//2)]=[{'N':nord,'S':sud,'E':est,'O':ovest},'']
            #la stringa vuota è lo stato della cella


    return maze
```

For example a maze is:

```
{(0, 0): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': True}, ''], (0, 1): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': True}, ''], (0, 2): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (0, 3): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (0, 4): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (1, 0): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (1, 1): [{'N': False, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (1, 2): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (1, 3): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (1, 4): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (2, 0): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (2, 1): [{'N': False, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (2, 2): [{'N': False, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (2, 3): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (2, 4): [{'N': False, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (3, 0): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': True}, ''], (3, 1): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'O': True}, ''], (3, 2): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (3, 3): [{'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (3, 4): [{'N': False, 'S': False, 'E': True, 'O': True}, ''], (4, 0): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': True}, ''], (4, 1): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (4, 2): [{'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'O': False}, ''], (4, 3): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'O': False}, ''], (4, 4): [{'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'O': True}, '']}
```

I need to write a function that prints my maze like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uRcU.png)

Can someone help me?

I tried to build a function but it seems very long...

```
def stampa(L):
labirinto=[]
for r in range(righe_colonne(L)[0]):
    riga=[]
    for cella in celle(L):
        if cella[0]==r:
            if L[cella][0]['O']==True:
                riga.append('|   ')

            if L[cella][0]['O']==False:
                riga.append('    ')

            if cella[1]==righe_colonne(L)[1]-1:
                if L[cella][0]['E']==True:

                    riga.append('|')
                if L[cella][0]['E']==False:
                    riga.append('   ')




    labirinto.append(''.join(str(x) for x in riga))
    #cosi ho le righe pari, quelle che contengono le celle.
    #ora voglio le righe fra le celle
labirinto2=[]
for r in range(righe_colonne(L)[0]):
    riga=['+']
    for cella in celle(L):
        if cella[0]==r:

            if L[cella][0]['N']==True:

                riga.append('---+')
            if L[cella][0]['N']==False:
                riga.append('   +')


    labirinto2.append(''.join(str(x) for x in riga))

m=''
for e in range(0, len(labirinto)):
     m+=labirinto2[e]+'\n'+labirinto[e]+'\n'

#aggiungo l'ultima riga
riga=[]
for cella in celle(L):
    if cella[0]==righe_colonne(L)[0]-1:
        if L[cella][0]['S']==True:
            riga.append('+---')
        if L[cella][0]['S']==False:
            riga.append('    ')
riga.append('+')
m+=(''.join(str(x) for x in riga))
m+='\n'

print(m)
```

Comment: And what do you have so far?

Comment: On what type of media do you want to print it? In browser as HTML/CSS? In console as plain text?

Comment: Also: how to treat situation if two ajacent cells have borders? E.g. `{(0,0):[{"E":True}], (0,1): [{"W":True}]}`. Is border should be double in this case?

Comment: No, the border is one. I need to write a function that prints the maze in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib` for that purpose:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i, j in maze:
    walls, _ = maze[i, j]
    if walls['N']:
        plt.plot([i, i+1], [j+1, j+1], 'b-')
    if walls['E']:
        plt.plot([i+1, i+1], [j, j+1], 'b-')
    if walls['S']:
        plt.plot([i, i+1], [j, j], 'b-')
    if walls['O']:
        plt.plot([i, i], [j, j+1], 'b-')

plt.show()
```

For your example this gives:

[image]

Comment: Other solutions without matplotlib?